# Count Days in SQL SERVER in Case When Clause

Tags: sql-server

I have Table

```
1        2013-10-01 08:21        Null               Null        Null
1        2013-10-01 14:30        Null               Null        Null
2        2013-10-01 08:31        Null                Lt         Null
2        2013-10-01 14:31         EO                Null        Null
3        2013-10-01 14:30         EO                Null       Ab here
```

this Table is Result from this query

```
 SELECT m.ID,L.Log_D,W.Sat,L.C,
   (CASE WHEN convert(time,L.Log_D)>'08:31:00' and convert(time,L.Log_D)<'10:30:00' and L.C =1  then 'Lt'end )as Late,
     (CASE WHEN convert(time,L.Log_D)<'13:30:00'  and L.C =2  then 'Ab'end )as EarlyOut,
     (CASE WHEN DATENAME(DAY, day( L.Log_D)) =2 THEN 'Ab'  END) as Counte
   from WorkPeriod W,LogT L,MinimumInfoT m  where  day(L.Log_D) =1 
   and month(L.Log_D) =10
   and year(L.Log_D) =2013 
   and W.id=54 
   and m.Branch_ID=35 
   and L.C in(1,2) 
   and M.ID =L.EmpId 
   and W.id =m.W_Period 
   group by m.ID,L.Log_D,W.Sat,L.C 
   order by m.ID
```

I need the Absent Column Display as 'Ab' when the count Of the Day is less then  2 for each Id is that possible any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Window Function to do this:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ID) < 2 THEN 'ab' ELSE NULL END as Counte
```

This will get a count of records for each distinct `m.ID`. If the count for the current `m.ID` is less than 2, then it spits out `ab`.

Comment: Thank you @JNevill Very Much it is Worked

Comment: @MohameadBashear Being a new user, I'll upvote for you, BUT only you can ACCEPT the answer.